# Multiple DataCacheClients - Strange configuration behaviour

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-caching, appfabric-cache, azure-in-role-cache

I am using Azure's In-Role caching for our web role cluster.

I need to use separate `dataCacheClients` so to have different and explicitly set transport property configurations (`maxBufferPoolSize` and `maxBufferSize`).

The problem is that each `dataCacheClient` is always set with the same `maxBufferPoolSize` and `maxBufferSize` values.  They are all set to the values from the `dataCacheFactory` which I instantiate first.

```
<dataCacheClients>
  <dataCacheClient name="DataCache1">
    <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="MyRoleName" />
    <transportProperties maxBufferPoolSize="6400000" maxBufferSize="256" />
  </dataCacheClient>
  <dataCacheClient name="DataCache2">
    <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="MyRoleName" />
    <transportProperties maxBufferPoolSize="0" maxBufferSize="10485760" />
  </dataCacheClient>
  <dataCacheClient name="DataCache3">
    <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="MyRoleName" />
    <transportProperties maxBufferPoolSize="3276800" maxBufferSize="32768" />
  </dataCacheClient>
</dataCacheClients>
```

Each concrete `DataCache` object is instantiated from separate `DataCacheFactory` instances (contained inside static 'managers').  I have also tried reverting to creating the cache clients programmatically, but to no avail.

So, here is an exception being thrown due to MaxBufferSize being too small at 256.

[image: DataCacheException thrown]

When debugging the factory, you can clearly see that the MaxBufferSize is not 256:

[image: MaxBufferSize debugging]

I am starting to pull my hair out, so I've come up with the two ideas:

My suspicion is that the `StartPort` and `DiscoveryPort` in each data clients' `AutoDiscoveryProperties` are the same across all (22233 as `StartPort` and 24233 as `DiscoveryPort`), which makes me believe that they could be pulling from the same factory (and thus using the same settings).

In addition, the `DataCacheServerEndpoint` for each client is also the same, at 20004.  Perhaps they need to be different?

I am using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching 2.4.0.0 and Azure SDK 2.4.

**Can anyone help point me in the right direction?**

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is not client site, but server side. Make sure your maxBufferSize at your server is the right size, [sample configuration msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790816(v=azure.10).aspx):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <!--configSections must be the FIRST element -->
<configSections>
   <!-- required to read the <dataCacheClient> element -->
   <section name="dataCacheClient"
         type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientSection,
            Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, 
            Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
          allowLocation="true"
          allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
</configSections>

   <dataCacheClient requestTimeout="15000" channelOpenTimeout="3000" maxConnectionsToServer="1">
      <localCache isEnabled="true" sync="TimeoutBased" ttlValue="300" objectCount="10000"/>
      <clientNotification pollInterval="300" maxQueueLength="10000"/>
      <hosts>
         <host name="CacheServer1" cachePort="22233"/>
         <host name="CacheServer2" cachePort="22233"/>
      </hosts>
      <securityProperties mode="Transport" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
      <transportProperties connectionBufferSize="131072" maxBufferPoolSize="268435456" 
                           maxBufferSize="8388608" maxOutputDelay="2" channelInitializationTimeout="60000" 
                           receiveTimeout="600000"/>
   </dataCacheClient>
</configuration>
```

[Azure host configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790928.aspx)

Comment: How would I go about checking this for Azure In-Role caching?

Comment: I'm still not sure that is for Azure.  I have searched for the "DistributedCacheService.exe.config" file on the role instances, but nothing is found.

Comment: I have [created a new post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591401/cache-host-config-in-azure-in-role-caching) to troubleshoot my host configuration problem.  I cannot find this file!

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following snippet:

```
        // DataCacheFactoryConfiguration encapsulates the datacache client section of the config. 
        DataCacheFactoryConfiguration dcfc1 = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration("DataCache1");
        DataCacheFactory dcf1 = new DataCacheFactory(dcfc1);
        DataCache dc1 = dcf1.GetDefaultCache();
```

Alternatively you can configure it programmatically:

```
        // This will create an instance of DataCacheFactoryConfiguration from default datacache client in config.
        DataCacheFactoryConfiguration dcfc = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();
        //You can then set the buffer size as you wish and create DataCacheFactory and DataCache after that.
        dcfc.TransportProperties.MaxBufferSize = size;
        DataCacheFactory dcf = new DataCacheFactory(dcfc);
        DataCache dc = dcf.GetDefaultCache();
```

Edit1: I created two different client using two different factories and I can see both of them having different max buffer size.

```
        DataCacheFactoryConfiguration dcfc = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();
        dcfc.TransportProperties.MaxBufferSize = 8388608;
        DataCacheFactory dcf = new DataCacheFactory(dcfc);
        DataCache dc = dcf.GetDefaultCache();

        DataCacheFactoryConfiguration dcfc1 = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();
        dcfc1.TransportProperties.MaxBufferSize = 8388;
        DataCacheFactory dcf1 = new DataCacheFactory(dcfc1);
        DataCache dc1 = dcf1.GetDefaultCache();
```

Comment: The startPort, discoveryPort and dataCacheServerEndpoint are all server properties(ie where the client needs to connect to server). I tried creating two different clients using two different factories and I can see both have different max buffer size.