# Cache Host config in Azure In-Role caching

Tags: azure, appfabric, appfabric-cache, azure-appfabric, azure-in-role-cache

Accordingly to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790928(v=azure.10).aspx) (on AppFabric Caching, which is what Azure is run on), I should be able to find a `DistributedCacheService.exe.config` file located at `\Windows\System32\AppFabric`, but it doesn't exist on any of the instances.

When remoting into one of the instances and searching for configs, I find several cache-related config files in `E:\plugins\Caching`.

The `CacheService.config.exe` file looks very promising (similar to `DistributedCacheService .exe.config`), except that the `dataCacheConfig` is not initialized:

```
<dataCacheConfig cacheHostName=""> 
  <!-- Comment/uncomment below line to disable/enable file sink logging.
  Also location attribute is not honored. It is just specified since its mandatory. -->
  <!--<log logLevel="3" location="" />-->
  <clusterConfig connectionString="" />
</dataCacheConfig>
```

I need to confirm that certain data cache settings are being configured properly on the server side in order to solve [a previous post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413752/multiple-datacacheclients-strange-configuration-behaviour).

My client-side `web.config` looks something like this:

```
<dataCacheClients>
  <dataCacheClient name="DataCache1">
    <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="MyRoleName" />
    <transportProperties maxBufferPoolSize="6400000" maxBufferSize="256" />
  </dataCacheClient>
  <dataCacheClient name="DataCache2">
    <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="MyRoleName" />
    <transportProperties maxBufferPoolSize="0" maxBufferSize="10485760" />
  </dataCacheClient>
  <dataCacheClient name="DataCache3">
    <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="MyRoleName" />
    <transportProperties maxBufferPoolSize="3276800" maxBufferSize="32768" />
  </dataCacheClient>
</dataCacheClients>
```

**Where do I find the cache host configuration file in Azure In-Role caching (colocated)?**

Answer (score 0):

The host property that you configure in on premise AppFabric cache is dynamically initialized in InRole Cache. You can check Caching.csplugin at Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure.NET SDK\v2.2\bin\plugins\Caching to see the endpoints for the cache server.